# Express Server issue with MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

Just started Express server module in my school. I have made a very simple website just to try it but it seems that the css file is not being executed (checked in chrome's terminal cl).

1. Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
   home:26
2. GET http://localhost:3000/public/einstein-home.jpg 404 (Not Found)

```js
const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(express.static('public')); 
    
    
    app.get('/home', (request, response) => {
        console.log('dirname', __dirname);
        response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/home.html')
    });
    
    app.get('/about', (request, response) => {
        console.log('dirname', __dirname);
        response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/about.html')
    });
    
    app.get('/works', (request, response) => {
        console.log('dirname', __dirname);
        response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/works.html')
    });
    
    
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('Website about Einstein');
    });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8%;
    background-color: #52bad5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2C9AB7;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li:hover a {
    color: #2C9AB7;
}

.text {
    width: 90%;
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 25px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #A3A3A3;
}
.about {
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.foot {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #717070;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border-top-width: 2px;
}


.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/style.css">
        <script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n2:default.js"></script>  

    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container"> 
  
  <header> <a href="">
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#hero">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#work">WORK</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <img src="/public/einstein.jpg" width="auto" height="361" alt=""/>
  <section class="about" id="about">
    <h2 class="hidden">About</h2>
    <p class="text">Welcome "Einsteiners". Feel free to find navigate in our website.</p>
</section>

  <footer>
    <article class="footer_column"> </article>
    <article class="footer_column"> </article>
  </footer>

  <div class="foot">e=mc2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please send me some feedback regarding this issue?

Cheers!

Comment: Most likely issue here is that you URL is incorrect. The `mime type` message is a red herring. You do not need `public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can strongly recommend not rolling your own templating: express comes with `ejs` built in, and if you need something more elaborate, [adding better templating](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) through `pug` or `nunjucks` are perfectly fine options. Rely on [res.render()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) to generate your HTML files, don't use `res.write` or `res.sendFile`.

As for why things are not working properly, remember to [read up on how `static` works](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express): you tell Express which directories it needs to check for URL requests before moving on to the "real" routes, where -crucially- the name of the dir *does not map* to the URLs.

I.e. if you have this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.static('files'))
```

then a request to `yoursite.tld/css/cake.css` will first check for `css/cake.css` inside `public`, then inside `files`, and *then* it'll fall through to whatever `app.get` routes might match if there is no path match.

Comment: Thank you @Mike. Dind't need to use the /public on href. Cheers!